# Is it ok if I have many extremely short, and "elementary" questions to ask on Stack, and I just merged them in 1 question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, best-practices

They may or may not be of similar topics.

I am afraid I would spam up the site and push other more important questions to the bottom, if I listed them as individual questions...

And I have about 20 questions on my hand right now...

Comment: Would you perhaps give an example of such a question here?

Comment: Well, it is not possible to "spam up the site" because there are [question quotas](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770) which prevent this.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah I see. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Related question was discussed here [Posting multiple questions as one?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one) Based on what you can read there, it seems quite possible, that a question combined from several unrelated questions could be closed. Of course, if some of the questions are very similar or closely related, it should be ok to merge them into one question. (At least in my opinion.) Or you could ask one of them and after you see the answers you could try to solve similar questions by yourself using similar methods.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- [Don't post multiple questions as one question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6464/856)
- [Don't spam the site with too many questions.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4742/856)

So, what should you do? Take it easy and ask a few questions at a time, respond to the comments, read the answers and take your time to absorb them. Come back the next day and ask a few more questions. And so on.

(Thanks to Martin Sleziak for gathering the relevant links.)

Comment: But what if my homework is due tomorrow and it has 20 problems? :)

Comment: @GEdgar: A sock puppet is what you need. or cry out loud. :)

Comment: That's when I would gladly suggest the spoon-feeding services over at answers.yahoo ...

Comment: Is this dogmatic, or could there be exceptions in case the questions are all intended to get at one central idea?  For example, would it be reasonable to quote a single math-related paragraph on Wikipedia, and ask several specific questions to break down the overarching question "what does this paragraph mean," rather than asking "what does A represent in Text X," "what does B + E represent in Text X," "is Text X assuming a rectangular coordinate system," etc., each as separate questions?